# Weird Mathematica Crash

Tags: crash

One hour ago, my `Mathematica` 10.4 StudentEdition, completely crashed, stopped to respond, after I typed 2 letters. For example I wanted to type the command `Abs` or `Exp` or `Plot` and after the second letter it stopped typing and stopped responding. It is really weird, I used task manager, I restarted the PC, afterwards I shut it down and restarted it, but there is no difference. Each time I did that It crashed. This happens only with *letters*, not with numbers, not with symbols.

It have never happened again, and this period I am using it on a daily basis.

Any idea what kind of trouble is it and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the folder

$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/Functional‌​Frequency

and see if there are any unusually large files there (>100 Kb or so). If any such files exist, please delete them. The file CodeAssistHistory10.3.m is often the culprit, and is safe to delete.